# Thin white line border appears around entire PDF page when exported from Indesign CC

Tags: adobe-indesign, export, adobe-acrobat

Any pdf documents I export from Indesign CC 2017 version 12.1.0.56 has a white border around the pdf page. If I place an image that covers the entire page in indesign the pdf page in acrobat pro dc or acrobat reader dc will have a 1 px size white border around the entire page. This occurs even if I place a solid colored rectangle that covers the entire page.  Oddly enough, if I place a smaller solid colored rectangle inside the page that has a solid colored rectangle that covers the entire page, the smaller rectangle does not have a white border. This issue happens even if I only place a thin colored sold rectangle that is flush with one edge of the page in Indesign.  The problem still persists even if I expand the rectangle into the paste board.

If I view the pdf in any other pdf viewer such as older versions of acrobat reader like xi or foxit pdf viewer, the white border does not appear.  I have read many forum posts and articles on this issue but I can't figure out how to fix this issue.  I have tried zooming in and out, changing the theme color in acrobat dc, turning off "smooth line art" option in the preferences etc. and nothing helps. Here is a screen shot, any help would be appreciated, thanks:

[image]

Comment: Did you experiment with Page Display Settings in Acrobat? Like "Always show document page size" or "Show Art, Trim & Bleed Boxes"?

Comment: @AAGD Yes, but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a feature of Acrobat Reader DC.  It has nothing to do with InDesign because the same thing happens with PDFs created in Illustrator, and Inkscape, and other software - I just checked.

I did notice if you click View > Display Theme, and change from light to dark gray, it goes away - so I guess it's part of the "light gray" display theme.

I guess you could complain to Adobe.

Comment: Changing the theme to dark gray does remove the white lines, but it's a user initiated settings change. It would be great if the white lines don't appear by default with the normal/default viewing settings. Thanks for your answer. Maybe do I have to do something different in Indesign to make it compatible with the new Acrobat DC line of PDF readers?

Comment: I'm not sure if you fully understand what I am saying here. The white line you are seeing is not caused by something in the PDF or a setting in the software used to created the PDF, it's caused by Adobe Reader DC itself.

Comment: I understand that, but I was just wondering if changing anything in indesign would remove the white lines. But like you said, it has nothing to do with indesign.